# how to show Build Bundle /APK in android studio

Tags: android

The opetion of creating apk file called Build Bundle below Build list in android studio that doesn't apear in the list. How can I show that option in the list shown in this figure?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYI3n.png)

I want to know how to apear that option called Buld Bundle to create apk file

Comment: In this picture you posted shows that seems your develop environment doesn't already. You should install jdk and gradle to the environment (aka your pc) by click the error in output window automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have successfully synced your project. If there are any errors resolve them before proceeding.

If the "Generate Signed Bundle" button is not visible, you can open the setting and create the shortcut key for "Generate Signed Bundle"

[image: See Attachment]